# code breaks after if else function in C

Tags: c, if-statement

So my code keeps breaking after the ending curly brace in my if else function I made.
Does it have something to do with the return EXIT_SUCCES, am I using it wrong?

Here's my code:

```
//  recursive.c
//  lynda

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 checks for traffic light if else example
 */
void processColor(char c);
void checkTraficLight(void);
int main(void){
    checkTraficLight();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void checkTraficLight(void){
    printf("what is the light? r, y, g: \n");
    char color;
    scanf("%c", &color);
    processColor(color);
}

void processColor(char c){
    if (c == 'r') {
        printf("color is red");
    } else if (c == 'y'){
        printf("color is yellow");
    } else if(c == 'g'){
        printf("color is green");
    } else {
        printf("U entered an invalid color");
    }
}
```

---

[update from comment:]

But the thing is that it stops before it prints out what I wanted it to print out let's say I input "r" it should print out "color is red" but instead it just says "(lldb) and stops, it doesn't print out "color is red"

Comment: Could you be more specific? Programs don't "break". They either crash or don't act as expected. Please provide an error message or some sample output.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking?"

Comment: your program is running fine, may be you want to add loop in your program.

Comment: what I mean by break is the error message says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" and it shows up at the very last curly brace

When run my program and give it an input, it stops there and comes up with this message and doesn't execute anymore code.

Also, this is C

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the symptom of you "code keeps breaking"? Please always add the precise error message or failure symptom to your questions!

Comment: @user3724487 probably you are running your code in a debugger and it says that when it gets to the end of the program. It doesn't execute any more code because it finished executing all the code already.

Comment: But the thing is that it stops before it prints out what I wanted it to print out let's say I input "r" it should print out "color is red" but instead it just says "(lldb) and stops, it doesn't print out "color is red"

Answer (score 0):

I have runned your code on codeblocks 13.12 assuming it's a c++ code. It works fine with no bugs nor crashes.

The structure of your code and the comment of the first line makes me thing you want to write a recursive function. If so, you shoud give more details on the goal of that function.

Comment: This somehow does not answer the question at all. I might have suite as comment though.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("color is red");
```

`printf()` prints to Standard Output (aka `stdout`). `stdout` is line buffered by default, so its content is not written out as long as no new-line is to be printed.

As the code shown does not print any new-lines nothing is printed out.

To fix this append a trailing new-line to what should be printed:

```
printf("color is red\n");
```

Or explicitly flush `stdout` by doing

```
printf("color is red");
flush(stdout);
```